# Can MediaElement play QuickTime (.mov) files?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm building a Windows Phone 7.5 app that needs to play videos that are pulled from a remote XML feed. Some of these videos are in .mov format, while others are in .mp4 format. The .mp4's play just fine, but the .mov's don't play (just a blank screen). I'm using MediaElement to play these files. Is there any way to make MediaElement play .mov files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a Windows Phone? No.

The `MediaElement` uses whatever codecs are available and installed. Since you can't install your own codecs and only ships with a [certain number of codecs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087.aspx), you cannot play them.

The QuickTime Format is just a container around MPEG-4 - it should be very simple to transcode them to MP4 (Which is supported) if you have control over the source.

Comment: That's the problem - I don't have control of the source. Thank you for the input though.